# Gem installed in @global gemset is not available in other gemsets

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemset

I installed `rvm` and then installed [`bropages`](http://bropages.org/) in @global gemset.

```
$ rvm install 2.2.3
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.3@global
$ gem install bropages
```

When I run

```
$ gem list | grep bro
bropages (0.1.0)
```

I can see bropages is installed. But when I move to default gemset it is not available.

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.3@default
$ gem list | grep bro # Result is empty
```

I also tried [official way](https://rvm.io/gemsets/global).

```
$ rvm ruby-2.2.3@global do gem install bropages
Successfully installed bropages-0.1.0
Parsing documentation for bropages-0.1.0
Done installing documentation for bropages after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But it too didn't work.

Running `bro` command in default gemset gives this error,

```
$ bro
/Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bropages' (>= 0) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3 /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global:/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin/bro:22:in `<main>'
```

I have tried these links but they didn't help at all.

1. [How to install gem across all gemsets when using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707604/how-to-install-gem-across-all-gemsets-when-using-rvm)
2. [RVM - Not able to use gems from the @global gemset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952565/rvm-not-able-to-use-gems-from-the-global-gemset)
3. [How do I use RVM and create globally available gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552937/177116)

Ruby 2.2.3 is the only version installed. My shell is Fish.

---

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529350/gem-installed-in-global-gemset-is-not-available-in-other-gemsets?noredirect=1#comment52923261_32529350)

> from the default gemset run: `echo $GEM_HOME - $GEM_PATH` from the global `gemset run: gem list -d bro`

Output is as follows,

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.3@default
Using /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
$ echo $GEM_HOME - $GEM_PATH
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3 - /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3 /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global

$ rvm use ruby-2.2.3@global
Using /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3 with gemset global
$ gem list -d bro

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bropages (0.1.0)
    Author: bropages.org
    Homepage: http://bropages.org
    Installed at: /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global

    Bro
```

Comment: from the default gemset run: `echo $GEM_HOME - $GEM_PATH`

from the global gemset run: `gem list -d bro`

Comment: @mpapis I have updated the question with output.

Comment: your `$GEM_PATH` is set wrong, it has a space instead of colon

Comment: @mpapis there was a bug in the rvm recommended script for fish shell. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529350/gem-installed-in-global-gemset-is-not-available-in-other-gemsets?noredirect=1#comment53005059_32569530).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your `GEM_PATH` is broken, pleas run:

```
export GEM_PATH=/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global
```

and try again:

```
bro
```

Comment: Thanks. Replacing ` ` in `GEM_PATH` with `:` fixed the issue for me. This raises another problem, every time I install a ruby, rvm sets `GEM_PATH` incorrectly. Can you please tell me where does rvm set `GEM_PATH` so that I can fix the issue for all rubies?

Comment: I think this issue is due to using rvm in fish shell. I installed a new ruby version in bash shell, and rvm set `GEM_PATH` correctly. But when I install ruby in the fish shell, the `:` in `GEM_PATH is replaced with ` `, which then breaks the gems.

Comment: rvm [official documentation](https://rvm.io/integration/fish) recommends [this script](https://github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/blob/master/functions/rvm.fish) for fish shell. I suspect this line is the culprit https://github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/blob/master/functions/rvm.fish#L7

Comment: Ok so this issue has already been noticed and fixed here https://github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/pull/16

Comment: The patch was not accepted into the upstream when I created this question. The patch fixes the issue.